# Images move on zoom in, but stay on zoom out

Tags: html, css

I am making a site for a school project. Everything was going well until I zoomed my creation, the facebook icon and map hyperlink started moving left, their position didn't seem a problem on zooming out since they were exactly as they had to be. My code is clumsy written, I've just started learning CSS so please leave a negative response.

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("backgr.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.site {
    background-image: url("repet.jpg");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.all {
    position: relative;
}
.lin {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.fc {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 300px;
    right: 0;
    top: 55%;
}
.map1 {
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: "Myriad-Pro", Calibri;
    letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    font-style: condensed;
    font-size: 130%;
    color: white;
    left: 85px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 53.2%;
}
.map2 {
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: "Myriad-Pro", Calibri;
    letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    font-style: condensed;
    font-size: 130%;
    color: white;
    left: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="all">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/MumbaiIndianStruma31Burgas/?fref=ts">
        <img src="fc.png" class="fc">
    </a>

    <a class="map1" href="https://www.google.bg/maps/place/Mumbai+Indian+Restaurant/@42.5047587,27.4665381,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x40a69490c9140d5d:0xe145b9d1e18c51ee">
 Карта
 </a>

    <a class="map2" href="https://www.google.bg/maps/place/Mumbai+Indian+Restaurant/@42.5047587,27.4665381,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x40a69490c9140d5d:0xe145b9d1e18c51ee">
Map
</a>
    <div class="site">
        <img src="line.jpg" class="lin">
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/u5gyo99c/)

Comment: I've added a demo to your question, but the images are broken. Please fix them so we can better see the problem, and update the link.

Comment: Its because images are made by me, not found in the internet, I don't know with what i can replace them.

Comment: http://placehold.it, http://lorempixel.com

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u5gyo99c/2/#&togetherjs=3yz2n0rGSl

Comment: Thanks. Normally we don't post collaboration sessions, though. Just the fiddle. By "... and update the link" I meant edit your question to update it.

Comment: Edit my question to update it?
I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Padding left, Padding Right and margin option to set the image